# Is there a way to change flow of pixels from right to left in css rather than the normal left to right

Tags: css

Say for example we have an element (let's call it contact-box) that is always on the right of the page and we want a series of different width images to run along side it's left hand side. The right hand edge of each image should always be 20px from the left hand edge of the contact-box.

If we know the width and positioning of the contact-box and we set the right attribute on the images then it calculates from the left hand edge of the image rather than the right. This is not going to achieve the desired result as the images are of variable width.

Is there a way to switch this behaviour on a per element basis to flow from right to left instead or is the only way to grok it in javascript?

Edit: To be clear - The right edge of the images align 20px to the left of the left edge of the contact-box container element. Images are variable width and responsive as is the contact-box.

The image below is an example of how the elements might be positioned.

[image: This is an example of the positioning of the elements]

Comment: I'd like to see an image of what you are trying to achieve, but from the description, it sounds like you want a column of images, all aligned to their right-edges, with the aligned right edge positioned 20px to the RIGHT of the LEFT edge of the contact-box container element... correct?

Comment: Essentially yes but with the right edge of the images aligned 20px to the left of the left edge of the contact-box container element.

Comment: Please see the image I have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I think I understand!  Make the image a child of `contact-box`.  Set `contact-box` to `position:relative`, and the child image to `position:absolute`.  Now set the image to `right:100%` and give it a `right-margin` of `20px`.

```
<div class="contact-box">
  contact-box
  <img class="goLeft" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.contact-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.contact-box img.goLeft {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%; /* aligns the right edge of the image to the left edge of the container*/
  margin-right: 20px; /* adds 20px spacing between the image and the container */
}
```

I floated the `contact-box` element to the right for the purpose of this demonstration, but it doesn't need to be floated for this to work.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/qvgknv4g/

*** Alternative Solution ***

You can also make use of CSS's `direction` property, and set it to `rtl` (for right-to-left).  This will use the browser's natural rendering flow, and the image is instead a sibling of `contact-box`:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="contact-box">
    contact-box
  </div>
  <img class="goLeft" src="http://placehold.it/180x150" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.outer {
  direction: rtl;  /* This makes the magic happen */
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.contact-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top; /* by default the image will render bottom-aligned to the text in conten-box.  This fixes that. */
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/qvgknv4g/2/

Comment: This is great. The second solution was what I was thinking about when I asked the question but I couldn't figure out how to the the 'rtl' to work. Both solutions are very nice. 

Thanks for the lesson :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to position the image inside the contact box and assign `position: absolute;` to it. Make sure the contact box container has `position: relative; or`absolute`, otherwise positioning of the image will not work as expected.

Then apply the contact box's width + your 20px to the `right` attribute.

```
.contactbox {
    position: relative;
}
.contactbox img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 220px; /* example in case your box is 200px wide */
    top: 0;
}
```

Ofc, this only works if your contactbox doesn't have `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The the right edge of the images aligned 20px to the left of the left edge of the contact-box container element. Images are variable width and responsive as is the contact-box.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear, but I think this is what you're asking for:

If you can add a wrapper around your images, you can set the wrapper to a width of however far from the left-hand edge you want, then float the images to the right.

In your case it would be something like:

HTML

```
<div id="contact-box">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width:20px;
}
img {
    float:right;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3hxjp89r/

Keep in mind that in the fiddle above I tweaked the numbers just to show how it works. If you truly want the images 20px from the edge and right-aligned, then change the width of the `#container` div.

Comment: The floating of images is correct but the images should be outside of the contact box. Please see the image I added to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you have a contact-box on the right of the page, and you want a column of images floated right, and each exactly 20px away from the contact-box.

Sounds simple enough:

```css
#contact-box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fda;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
#images {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#images > img {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #123;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img width="200" height="150" alt="one">
  <img width="240" height="150" alt="two">
  <img width="200" height="150" alt="three">
  <img width="360" height="150" alt="four">
  <img width="210" height="150" alt="five">
</div><div id="contact-box">
  Contact Box
</div>
```